# How do I tell gcc to use a specific instantiation of glibc?

Tags: gcc, glibc

For "reasons", I need to build an x86 toolchain that emits no SIMD instructions (trying to use `-march` isn't enough because glibc will include functions that are built to use SIMD instructions, etc.).

I have built my own gcc 5.3 using the following configure flags:

```
../src/gcc/configure --prefix=/scratch/install --enable-languages=c,c++ \
--with-cpu=ivybridge \
--with-arch=ivybridge \
CFLAGS="-march=ivybridge" \
CXXFLAGS="-march=ivybridge"
```

I then built my own glibc using the following configure flags:

```
../src/glibc/configure --prefix=/scratch/install --with-arch=ivybridge \
CC="/scratch/install/bin/gcc" \
CXX="/scratch/install/bin/g++" \
CFLAGS="-O2 -march=ivybridge" \
CXXFLAGS="-O2 -march=ivybridge -Wa,-march=corei7+nommx+nosse+noavx"`
```

I verified that my gcc is NOT using my glibc.

```
$ /scratch/install/bin/gcc  -print-file-name=libc.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
```

---

**Question:**

How do I link in my newly compiled glibc? I'm only interested in compiling `-static` binaries, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I verified that my gcc is NOT using my glibc.

Why would it?

You need to rebuild `gcc` again, adding `--with-sysroot=/scratch/install` (and possibly other flags).

In general, building *correct* linux-to-linux cross-compilers is quite tricky, and you may find that using [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) will save you quite a bit of trial and error.